# Why does Hibernate not support distributed transactions?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

Why  Hibernate not support distributed transactions, even though we can communicate with multiple databases using different cfg files Hibernate?

Comment: You need to elaborate and clarify your question, please.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate does support distributed transactions. It's just not Hibernate that will handle the transactions in that case, but an external JTA TransactionManager. And Hibernate code will execute in the context of the current JTA transaction.

That is described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-demarcation-jta).

Comment: can u pls send a sample code for this implementation

Comment: I posted a link to the documentation. The documentation has code examples. Read it.